# Android sorting ascending custom adapter by distance

Tags: android, sorting, adapter

in my app i have a list with custom item list that show different item load in background with adapter
I'm trying to sort in ascendig way (using distance value) the element of adapter with this code. Into onCretaeView:

```
cardViewList = new ArrayList<>();
    View vw=inflater.inflate(R.layout.jsonparse_fragment, container, false);
    lv=(ListView) vw.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lv.setDivider(null);
    lv.setDividerHeight(0);

    final Double lat = gpsTracker.getLatitude();
    Double LatitudineUber = lat;
    Double lon = gpsTracker.getLongitude();
    Double LongitudineUber = lon;





    cardViewList.clear();

    if (flag_above35==1 && flag_below35==0 && flag_hybrid==0 && flag_position==0 && flag_tempo==0 && flag_conducente == 0)
    {
        car2go_flag=1;
        new JSONAsynTask().execute("https://www.car2go.com/api/v2.1/vehicles?loc="+nome_citta+"&oauth_consumer_key=roadzapp&format=json");
    }
    else if (flag_above35==0 && flag_below35==1 && flag_hybrid==0 && flag_position==0 && flag_tempo==0 && flag_conducente == 0)
    {
        car2go_flag=2;
        new JSONAsynTask().execute("https://www.car2go.com/api/v2.1/vehicles?loc="+nome_citta+"&oauth_consumer_key=roadzapp&format=json");
    }
    else if (flag_above35==1 && flag_below35==0 && flag_hybrid==1 && flag_position==0 && flag_tempo==0 && flag_conducente == 0)
    {
        car2go_flag=3;
        new JSONAsynTask().execute("https://www.car2go.com/api/v2.1/vehicles?loc="+nome_citta+"&oauth_consumer_key=roadzapp&format=json");
    }
    else if (flag_above35==0 && flag_below35==1 && flag_hybrid==1 && flag_position==0 && flag_tempo==0 && flag_conducente == 0)
    {
        car2go_flag=4;
        new JSONAsynTask().execute("https://www.car2go.com/api/v2.1/vehicles?loc="+nome_citta+"&oauth_consumer_key=roadzapp&format=json");
    }
    else if (flag_above35==0 && flag_below35==0 && flag_hybrid==1 && flag_position==0 && flag_tempo==0 && flag_conducente == 0)
    {
        car2go_flag=5;
        new JSONAsynTask().execute("https://www.car2go.com/api/v2.1/vehicles?loc="+nome_citta+"&oauth_consumer_key=roadzapp&format=json");
    }
    else if (flag_above35==0 && flag_below35==0 && flag_hybrid==0 && flag_position==0 && flag_tempo==0 && flag_conducente == 0)
    {
        car2go_flag=0;
        new JSONAsynTask().execute("https://www.car2go.com/api/v2.1/vehicles?loc="+nome_citta+"&oauth_consumer_key=roadzapp&format=json");
        if (flag_uber==1) {
            uber_flag=0;
            new JSONAsynTask1(getContext().getApplicationContext()).execute();
        }
        if (flag_jcd==1) {
            jcd_flag=0;
            //new JSONAsynTask2().execute();
            new JSONAsynTask3().execute();
        }
        if (flag_bitaksi==1) {
            bitaksi_flag=0;
            new JSONAsynTask4(getContext().getApplicationContext()).execute();
        }
        if (flag_lyft==1) {
            lyft_flag = 0;
            new JSONAsynTask5().execute();
        }
    }
    else if (flag_above35==0 && flag_below35==0 && flag_hybrid==0 && flag_position==1 && flag_tempo==0 && flag_conducente == 0)
    {
        car2go_flag=6;
        new JSONAsynTask().execute("https://www.car2go.com/api/v2.1/vehicles?loc="+nome_citta+"&oauth_consumer_key=roadzapp&format=json");
        if (flag_uber==1) {
            uber_flag=1;
            new JSONAsynTask1(getContext().getApplicationContext()).execute();
        }
        if (flag_jcd==1) {
            jcd_flag=1;
            //new JSONAsynTask2().execute();
            new JSONAsynTask3().execute();
        }
        if (flag_bitaksi==1) {
            bitaksi_flag=1;
            new JSONAsynTask4(getContext().getApplicationContext()).execute();
        }
        if (flag_lyft==1) {
            lyft_flag=1;
            new JSONAsynTask5().execute();
        }
    }
    else if (flag_above35==0 && flag_below35==0 && flag_hybrid==0 && flag_position==0 && flag_tempo==1 && flag_conducente == 0)
    {
        car2go_flag=7;
        new JSONAsynTask().execute("https://www.car2go.com/api/v2.1/vehicles?loc="+nome_citta+"&oauth_consumer_key=roadzapp&format=json");
        if (flag_uber==1) {
            uber_flag=2;
            new JSONAsynTask1(getContext().getApplicationContext()).execute();
        }
        if (flag_bitaksi==1) {
            bitaksi_flag=2;
            new JSONAsynTask4(getContext().getApplicationContext()).execute();
        }
        if (flag_lyft==1) {
            lyft_flag=2;
            new JSONAsynTask5().execute();
        }
    }
    else if (flag_above35==0 && flag_below35==0 && flag_hybrid==0 && flag_position==0 && flag_tempo==0 && flag_conducente == 1)
    {
        //car2go_flag=8;
        //new JSONAsynTask().execute("https://www.car2go.com/api/v2.1/vehicles?loc="+nome_citta+"&oauth_consumer_key=roadzapp&format=json");
        if (flag_uber==1) {
            uber_flag=1;
            new JSONAsynTask1(getContext().getApplicationContext()).execute();
        }
        if (flag_bitaksi==1) {
            bitaksi_flag=1;
            new JSONAsynTask4(getContext().getApplicationContext()).execute();
        }
        if (flag_lyft==1) {
            lyft_flag=1;
            new JSONAsynTask5().execute();
        }
    }

    adapter = new CardViewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.new_item_list, cardViewList);
    Collections.sort(cardViewList, new Comparator<CardView>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(CardView lhs, CardView rhs) {
            Double d1 = Double.parseDouble(lhs.getDistance()) / 1000.0;
            Double d2 = Double.parseDouble(rhs.getDistance()) / 1000.0;
            if (d1 == d2) {
                return 0;
            }
            if (d1 > d2) {
                return 1;
            }
            return -1;
        }
    });


    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

but the sort doesn't work. 
My code is wrong?
Any help?

Comment: Man your code is really messy. No offense, just some constructive criticism. I'm sure you can do this better without so many if-elses and asynchtask creations. Also your problem is essentially what the first answer says: you need to wait for the data to run the sorting. ALSO: do not do parsing in the compare method, this is very inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cardviewlist is getting filled by an AsyncTask, so the call to `Collections.sort` happens before the list is filled, so there is nothing yet to sort. Later, as the AsyncTasks fill the list, they are not sorted.